# Webcam barcode reader: Exporting multiple barcode data to notepad

Tags: python, arrays, list, opencv, set

I have modified some code I found online that reads barcode from webcam using opencv/pyzbar.

It is able to read multiple barcode but when I tired to write it to a notepad, only 1 data appears.

I have tried saving the data read to an array/list and export but it doesn't work.

How can I get it to write all the distinct barcode to a notepad.

```
#import libraries
```

```
import cv2
import time
from pyzbar import pyzbar

def read_barcodes(frame):
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for barcode in barcodes:
        x, y , w, h = barcode.rect
        #1 Decode barcode/Create frame
        barcode_info = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

```
    #2 Create text on top of the barcode
    cv2.putText(frame, barcode_info, (x + 6, y - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 0, 255), 2)
    #3 Export to text 
    code = []
    if barcode_info in code:
        print("Duplicate")
    else:
        code.append(barcode_info)
        print (code)
        #set ={}
        #set.update(barcode_info)
    with open("barcode_result.txt", mode ='w') as file:
        for x in code:
            file.write("Recognized Barcode:" + x +"\n")
return frame

def main():
#1 Open webcam using OpenCV
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    #0(webcam) 1(camera)
ret, frame = camera.read()
#2 Loop till Esc is pressed
while ret:
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = read_barcodes(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Barcode/QR code reader', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
#3 Close webcam
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#4 
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

[Webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caovi.jpg)

[NotePad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU5qT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read all the code but it appear that you use 'w' mode to open the file, each time you do that, the file is erased before writing.

You probably need to use mode='a' for append.

for your second question, just move a bit your loop so it execute in the else statement. in your code it write in the file ignoring the if statement.

```
if barcode_info in code:
    print("Duplicate")
else:
    code.append(barcode_info)
    print (code)
    #set ={}
    #set.update(barcode_info)
    with open("barcode_result.txt", mode ='a') as file:
        for x in code:
            file.write("Recognized Barcode:" + x +"\n")
```

oh sorry didn't saw before

```
#3 Export to text 
code = []
if barcode_info in code: #this will never happen
    print("Duplicate")
```

you have to move your code = [] outside your loop, like at the initialisation of your program.

Something like:

```
    #2 Loop till Esc is pressed
code = []
while ret:
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = read_barcodes(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Barcode/QR code reader', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

#loop terminated, now write
with open("barcode_result.txt", mode ='a') as file:
        for x in code:
            file.write("Recognized Barcode:" + x +"\n")

#3 Close webcam
```

i didn't test because i can't use your library

```
def read_barcodes(frame):
...
#3 Export to text 
if barcode_info in code:
    print("Duplicate")
else:
    code.append(barcode_info)
    print (code)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! it is able to write multiple data now, but how do I get it to write distinct barcode data.